# Distinguish one machine from another in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I distinguish one machine from another in a batch file, so that

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\14.0
```

will be applied on one machine, while

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0
```

will be applied on another?

Comment: Use `%COMPUTERNAME%`?

Comment: Or type on the run dialogue: "cmd /k hostname" no quotes

Comment: Why do you care about the machine name?  Shouldn't you instead by looking for the existence of `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\'` or something?  If you were using Powershell instead, it would be really easy to check to see which was installed, then do the appropriate thing.

Comment: Thank you; I will use `if %COMPUTERNAME% == "" ()`. @Zoredache: This is just one of several commands that I want to run depending on the machine.